# periodic update location background Swift 3.0 iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, background, location

I making an app that when it enters in background I need that send to server some periodic data.
For wake up from background I use background update significant location(lower battery).
I noticed that the location is updated when phone cell from wifi/3g or when 3g changes cell tower , but my problem is that if user doesn't move ( and then cell tower doesn't change) the location does not update and the the app doest wake up and then I can't send data to server.

Do you know some method to solve this problem?

I do all those in AppDelegate file:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate ,  CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var manager = CLLocationManager()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

        return true
    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){

      sendDataToServer()
}
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}

}
```

Comment: Did you get any reasonable solution?

Answer (score 2):

The significant location change event is only triggered when there is a location change (ie cell tower change).  You should be using background fetch instead of location change to wake the app if what you need is to periodically download or upload data:

```
application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
```

then handle

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

https://github.com/paleksandrs/APScheduledLocationManager

Maximum 180s with background task.

Comment: I dont understand If your method uses significantLocationChanged or not. Because I can't use normal location but only battery low location